# how to push a column in slickgrid at particular index

Tags: model-view-controller, slickgrid

Hi i want to add a column on slickgrid at particular index.

I am trying to do `columns.push({ id: "", name: "", field: "" })`.

Its trying to add at last but i want this column in the middle of slickgrid. Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 2):

```js
var newColumn = { id: '', name: '', field: '' };

 // create a copy of the columns
var newColumns = grid.getColumns().slice(0);

// insert the new column in the middle somewhere
newColumns.splice(indexForNewColumn, 0, newColumn);

// set the grid's columns as the new columns
grid.setColumns(newColumns);
```